# Como instalar paquetes de Node js en AWS para función lambda

Tags: nodejs, aws, lambda

tengo una función lambda en la cual deseo utilizar el paquete [joi](https://openbase.io/js/joi-json/documentation), en el servicio lambda de aws, he revisado la documentación, pero no explica de forma clara donde se encuentra la terminal que se asocia al lambda o como instalar paquetes para node js.
muchas gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0):

Los paquetes debes descargarlos con `-s` o con `--save`. Este flag hace que los paquetes se descarguen en la carpeta de trabajo actual (bajo una subcarpeta llamada `node_modules`.

```
npm install -s express serverless-https
```

Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es crear un zip con tu código fuente y esta carpeta que acabas de crear, y usar el zip para definir el código fuente de la lambda